# ErrorException returns wrong file and line

Tags: php, exception

in file1.php:

```
set_error_handler('my_error_handler');
set_exception_handler('my_exception_handler');

function my_error_handler($errNo, $errStr, $errFile, $errLine, $whatever = null){
  // here ErrFile and $errLine are correct only for native funcs...
  throw New ErrorException($errStr, 0, $errNo, $errFile, $errLine);
}

function my_exception_handler($exception){
  print $exception->getLine(); // correct only for native functions
  print $exception->getFile(); // correct only for native functions
}
```

in file2.php, an example function definition:

```
function foo($requiredArg){

}
```

and in file3.php, calling foo:

```
  foo();
```

produces:

> Missing argument 1 for foo(), called in file3.php on line 2 and
>   defined...

The messsage is correct, but when I try to get the file and line with `$exception->getFile()` and `$exception->getLine()` (in my exception handler), I get the file and line where foo() was defined, not where it was called...

But with native PHP functions I get the file and line where the function was called (and this is what I want).

Comment: Can you confirm that you're getting the correct file name and line number when your error handler is called?

Comment: no, I get the same file and line :( Does that mean that PHP passes wrong arguments to my error handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question!

Things do seem to behave differently for native vs user defined functions.  One obvious thing though, can't really tell you where the function is defined if it's native because it's written in C, not PHP.  Would be nice to find out where it was called though, in the case of userspace code.  One way is to just parse that error message from a caught Exception, you can get the file and line where it was created.

```
function my_exception_handler($exception)
{
    $message = $exception->getMessage();
    $file    = $exception->getFile();
    $line    = $exception->getLine();

    if(strpos($message, 'called in') !== false) {
        preg_match('/called in .*php/', $message, $matches);
        $file = str_replace('called in ', '', $matches[0]);

        preg_match('/on line \d/', $message, $matches);
        $line = str_replace('on line ', '', $matches[0]);
    }

    echo 'line: ' . $line . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'file: ' . $file . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output based depiction from question with altered `my_exception_handler`:

```
line: 4
file: /tmp/file3.php
```

Answer (score 2):

It simply comes down to closest first.

When you use the core or built-in function, their definitions are included within the core of PHP. This would mean that a definition of the function is not available when compared to a user-defined function, whose definition is readily available.

If you run a `debug_backtrace();` or `$exception->getTrace();` inside your `exception_handler` function which references your user-defined functions' error, you will see the definition of the function first, and the calling of the function second. If you call an internal function, you will only see the calling line, as PHP cannot tell you the line of code within your script or included files that the internal function was defined, since it's defined in the core.

This is the order of operation of error handling. If you want to get the actual line which called the function, you can look into the trace and grab the second array's reference to line number.